# Populate the corresponding test method name on Sauce labs ondemand

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have ruby unit tests written using selenium-webdriver which are running on Sauce labs ondemand. When i lookup the test on sauce labs, the name corresponding to it is Unnamed Job. Is there a way to get the test method name populated there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that inside your setup method:

```rb
def setup
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer
  caps[:name] = name()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is! Just add the following key/value to your desired capabilities object:

```
"name": "my example name"
```

You can find more info about this as well as other configuration options in the Sauce Docs:
https://saucelabs.com/docs/ondemand/additional-config#name-your-jobs

Comment: I could get it added to the main class but how do i add it to each individual test case?

Answer (score 0):

Example code-
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability("name", "The Name of your test");

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code. Also, you should format your code in code blocks for better readability.

Comment: You could simply use the method setCapability(String key, Object Value) as i have explained above.